# Get angularjs app to work with another app (meteor)

Tags: angularjs, meteor, deployment, routes, ddp

I have a complex app deployed to an Apache2 server (hostinger). In my app,I wanted to have a link to a Meteor app I have created and make them both to work in the same domain. Is it possible? Do you have some instructions to share? Options are:

1) use a subdomain for Meteor only;

2) use multiple buildpacks in Heroku (how?);

3) use a specific route (using ngRouter) for a different architecture;

4) use DDP or RESTful api (will I need to set up Express and how?);

Please note I'm new to AngularJs and I will avoid using angular-meteor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it by creating CNAME and A entries in cPanel.

**A**

```
Host: sub    
points to: app's ip
```

**CNAME**

```
Host: * 
Points to: sub.herokuapp.com
```